# Inserting TeX code into beamer - Problem with otherkeywords

Tags: beamer, listings

I am preparing a `beamer` presentation and using the `lstlisting` environment in order to put in TeX code. I am using the following code which is largely copied from [here](http://texblog.org/tag/lstset/):

```
\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9} % defining color for listing
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} % defining color for listing

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX, texcsstyle=*\bf\color{blue},
numbers=left, breaklines=true, keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
commentstyle=\color{red}, otherkeywords={$}, frame=leftline,
tabsize=2, backgroundcolor=\color{lightgrey}}
```

I would like to also copy the `otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]},` line from tom ([here again](http://texblog.org/tag/lstset/)). However, it is always giving me error messages with that line. Is there something wrong with that code?

Thanks, Max

In response to the comment:
The error occurs I do this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{comment} % end and begin comment
\usepackage{dtklogos} % for \BibTeX

\usepackage{listings} % display code on slides; don't forget [fragile] option after \begin{frame}
\usepackage{bera} % pause in listing
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9} % defining color for listing
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} % defining color for listing

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
texcsstyle=*\bf\color{blue},
numbers=left,
breaklines=true,
keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
commentstyle=\color{red},
otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]},
frame=leftline,
tabsize=2,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgrey},
escapeinside=||
}


\begin{document}


\begin{lstlisting}
    \title[Title]{An Introduction to \LaTeX}
    \subtitle[Event]{ABC}
    \author[Author]{XXX} 
    \institute[University]{XYZ University}
    \maketitle
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I does not occur if I substitute  `otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]},` with  `otherkeywords={$},`

Comment: I did a simple test with your snippet and the line you want to use and got no errors, so something else must be going on in your document. Please edit your question and add a complete and minimal document allowing us to reproduce the problem mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm... aparently, you cannot use `otherkeywords` if `morekeywords` hasn't been previously used (this could be by design but I couldn't find a mention of this in the documenation); so simply adding the option `morekeywords={}` solves the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{comment} % end and begin comment
\usepackage{dtklogos} % for \BibTeX
\usepackage{listings} % display code on slides; don't forget [fragile] option after \begin{frame}
\usepackage{bera} % change font
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{lightgrey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9} % defining color for listing
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0} % defining color for listing

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
texcsstyle=*\bf\color{blue},
numbers=left,
breaklines=true,
keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
commentstyle=\color{red},
morekeywords={},
otherkeywords={$,\{ ,\} , [ , ] },
frame=leftline,
tabsize=2,
backgroundcolor=\color{lightgrey},
escapeinside=||
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}
    \title[Title]{An Introduction to \LaTeX}
    \subtitle[Event]{ABC}
    \author[Author]{XXX} 
    \institute[University]{XYZ University}
    \maketitle
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Gonzalo. I am a new users and you are really helping me out here!

Comment: Do you know why \subtitle and \institute don't turn blue?

Comment: @MCB yes; they are not standard keywords; they are defined only in some classes like `beamer`. You need to explicitly add them using `moretexcs={subtitle,institute},`

Comment: You are helping me out all day. Can I make amends somehow? Send you a few bugs via paypal or something like that?

Comment: @MCB no problem at all; I enjoy hanging around here to relax from work ;-) just by up-voting good answers and accepting the ones that best solved your problems (as you have been doing) is more than enough!